# how to use injection between MVP layers in android?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, mvp, dagger-2

I have been using using **dagger 2** in my project lately,

the problem is when I try to build my project, the presenter in my login
activity which  injected like below **is null**,

and when I try to build the project

**presenter cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method...**

I don't understand what have I done wrong??, please someone help me with this,

thanks in advance.

Here is my Login Activity, the presenter here is null, which shows that, I've not injected it properly

```
@Inject
LoginPresenter presenter;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    InjectHelper.getRootComponent().injectPresenter(this);
    presenter.setProgressBarVisiblity(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

this is my presenter module

```
 @Module
 public class PresenterModule {
 private final LoginActivity activity;

public PresenterModule(LoginActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public LoginActivity providesView() {

    return activity;
}
}


@Provides
@Singleton
public LoginPresenter providesPresenter()
{
    return new LoginPresenter();
}
}
```

this inject helper class

```
public class InjectHelper {
  private static RootComponent sRootComponent;

static {
    initModules();
}

private static void initModules() {
    sRootComponent = getRootComponentBuilder().build();
}

public static DaggerRootComponent.Builder getRootComponentBuilder() {
    return DaggerRootComponent.builder();
}

public static RootComponent getRootComponent() {
    if (sRootComponent == null) {
        initModules();
    }
    return sRootComponent;
}

}
```

this is root component class

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
     PresenterModule.class
})
public interface RootComponent {
void injectLoginView(LoginPresenter loginPresenter);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to inform the dagger which views want to use injection, in your component.
you must change the inject function code in your component to below:

```
    void inject(LoginActivity activity);
```

for showing dagger what you want, you need to use @dagger annotation NOT by sending it as inject function in component file. as you did properly:

```
@Inject
LoginPresenter presenter;
```

Dagger will search for a variable of type LoginPresenter in your module and finds the proper provider method using the type.

what you put in your component as a argument for "inject" function tells the Dagger what view you are going to do injection in (NOT what you want to inject)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {PresenterModule.class})
public interface RootComponent {
    void inject(LoginActivity activity);
}
```

Comment: Can you be more obvious, of course I want to inject presenter, what kind of answer is this?? Oo